# Cannot call a function from a static method

Tags: c#, console-application

Ok, this may sound like a very novice question.. i'm actually surprised i'm asking it. I can't seem to remember how to call a function from inside `static void Main()`

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main()
         {
              Run(); // I receive an error here.
              Console.ReadLine();
         }
         void Run()
         {
              Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
         }
    }
}
```

error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'myNameSpace.Program.Run()'

Comment: you should create reference for the class and call that method

Comment: Understanding the difference between static methods/properties/fields and instance versions of the same is a very important first step to programming.  I *strongly* suggest you pick up a copy of CLR Via C#.  Skip the first couple chapters (i.e., skip chapters that make your head spin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare your `Run()` method as static too:

```
static void Run()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: I had thought that, so I set it to static and the Console.WriteLine never appeared. Tried it again and all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to either make `Run` a `static` method or you need an object instance to call `Run()` of. So your alternatives are:

1.) Use an instance:

```
new Program().Run();
```

2.) Make `Run()` static:

```
static void Run()
{
   /..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make method static: `static void Run()`

Answer (score 2):

Run() must also be static or you need to create a new instance of the object like `new Program().Run();`

Answer (score 0):

cause static function is not associate with an instance. while the none static function must have an instance.
So you have to create a new instance (each way you want) and then call the function.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to encapsulate your Run() method inside a nested class and invoke it.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new NestedClass().Run();
    }

    class NestedClass
    {
        public void Run()
        { 
        }
    }
```